# Buffer size limit in Node

Tags: node.js, buffer

According to the docs:

https://nodejs.org/api/buffer.html#buffer_buffer_constants_max_length

There is a limit of 2GiB for buffers.

Is this a hard limit or can this be changed somehow?

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you're reading a json file, for big json files you should use json streaming, see this answer for more details: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44994896/433041