# fs.readFileSync() change max buffer size

Tags: javascript, node.js, buffer-overflow

I am using readFileSync() to read a file and get it as a buffer.

```js
let buffer = fs.readFileSync(path);
```

But, actually, node can't open a file bigger than ~2 GB.
Is there a way to enlarge the maximum allowed size of the buffer?
Or an alternative that also could return me the file as a buffer?

Thx

Comment: You can refer to this post for answer to this question - https://stackoverflow.com/a/54857532/2235057. But it is always suggested to use streams for reading large files in node.js instead of increasing memory or buffer size.

Comment: I understand, but, i'm not sure to undertstand how to modify it